# Getting the ratio that an oriented segment is divided by a line

Tags: geometry

I am hardly trying to understand vectors, but it is even harder than I expected...

I have the following drawing:

[image]

We have:

$ABCD - square$

$M $ - middle of $(CD)$

$DMNP - square$

Determine:

1. the ratio $BN$ divides $CD$ in
2. the ratio $BN$ divides $BP$ in

Comment: What do you mean by "the ratio $X$ divides $Y$ in"?

Comment: My native language is romanian, and maths is hard to translate for me. Look at this. It is in romanian, but you can understand the formulas: http://www.experior.ro/Docs/Impartirea_segmentului_AB_in_raportul_lambda_si_mijlocul_unui_segment/2. This is what I mean

Comment: Can you write in mathematical notation the quantity you are trying to determine?

Comment: Let $BN \cap CD = \{Q\}$. We say that $Q$ splits $\overrightarrow{CD}$ in ratio $k \Leftrightarrow\overline{QD} = k\overline{QC}$. I have to calculate $k$. Is it ok?

Comment: I think I understand, see my answer.  This question is more of a geometry question than a question about vectors.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $\overline{BN} \cap \overline{CD} = Q$.  Then $\triangle BCQ \sim \triangle NMQ$.  We know that $BC = 2NM$, so $CQ = 2MQ$.  Thus $CQ = \frac{2}{3}CM = \frac{1}{3} CD$.
2. $\overline{BN} \cap \overline{BP} = B$, so there's no meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

AB=2a and DM=a and let MN intersect AB in Q. $BN^2=NQ^2+QB^2=(2a+a)^2+a^2=9a^2+a^2=10a^2$. $BN=a\sqrt{10}$. $\frac{BN}{CD}=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}$.
$BP^2=9a^2+4a^2=13a^2$. $BP=\sqrt{13}$. $\frac{BN}{BP}=\frac{\sqrt{130}}{13}$.

Comment: I need a vector solution